# Custom progress bar in ios

Tags: ios, label, progress-bar

I am trying to make this custom bar where the label and the progress bar adjust according to each other's width..Is there an open source code for this.

[image]

Right now i am simply using a built in progress bar but i don't know how to adjust the progress bar and the text relative to the progress bar length.

```
    cell.candidatesPollProgress.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.candidatesPollProgress.progressTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.candidatesPollProgress.trackTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Where do i start?Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to make a UI like that of screenshot shared, you need to use a UIView with background color instead of UIprogressview. Set the UILabel(percentage text)'s Leading space Constraint to UIView(progress view)'s trailing end. Adjust UIView's width to `(progressValue)/(maxValue) * (max Width of Progress View)`

Comment: Thanks,exactly what i was looking for.